# Codeigniter Calendar Library Tutorial Update

Tags: codeigniter

following along with :[CodeIgniter from Scratch: The Calendar Library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-the-calendar-library/)

The code from the earlier version:

```
   class Mycal extends CI_Controller
{

    function display($month, $year) {

        $conf = array(
            'start_day' => 'Monday',
            'show_next_prev' => true,
            'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'mycal/display'
        );

        $this->load->library('calendar', $conf);

       print $this->calendar->generate($month, $year);  

    }
 }
```

generates these errors:

> > A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for Mycal::display()
>
> Filename: controllers/mycal.php
>
> Line Number: 4 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 2 for Mycal::display()
>
> Filename: controllers/mycal.php
>
> Line Number: 4 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: year
>
> Filename: controllers/mycal.php
>
> Line Number: 16 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: month
>
> Filename: controllers/mycal.php
>
> Line Number: 16

I updated to the following:

```
class Mycal extends CI_Controller {

    function display($year = null, $month = null) {

        $year = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $month = $this->uri->segment(4);

        $conf = array(
            'start_day' => 'Monday',
            'show_next_prev' => true,
            'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'mycal/display/'
        );

        $this->load->library('calendar', $conf);
        print $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);
    }

}
```

It works as desired, but is it following best practices for CI?

Answer (score 1):

When the `display` function is called, `$year` and `$month` will be set to the URI segments (or null) for you.  The `$this->uri->segment` call is not needed here.

Also `echo` is slightly faster than `print` ([according to this](http://www.learnphponline.com/php-basics/php-echo-vs-print)).

```
function display($year = null, $month = null) {
    $conf = array(
        'start_day' => 'Monday',
        'show_next_prev' => true,
        'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'mycal/display/'
    );

    $this->load->library('calendar', $conf);
    echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);
}
```

Comment: So why does the tutorial code fail, without $year = null, $month = null?

Comment: @Wasabi: How were you calling the URL?  In your updated version, you added `=null` after the parameters (default value).  If you went to `http://url/display` the first would fail as you're not passing any values to `display`, your updated code would have set `$month` and `$year` to `null`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the tutorial code works if you specify the year and month in the url, but if you don't it errors out.

Comment: @Catfish: Yes, exactly.  That's what I was trying to explain. :-P

Comment: @Rocket, The optional parameters were explained later in the video, outlining your reply. Many thanks to the always knowledgeable participants.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Rocket's answer, you need to set the year and month if they're not passed in the url.

By doing `$year = null, $month = null` as the parameters, it means that if no parameters are passed, $year will equal null and $month will equal null, but if parameters are passed in the url, $year will equal the first parameter and $month will equal the next parameter.

```
function display($year = null, $month = null) {

    $year = ($year == null) ? date('Y') : $year;
    $month = ($month == null) ? date('n') : $month;

    $conf = array(
        'start_day' => 'Monday',
        'show_next_prev' => true,
        'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'mycal/display/'
    );

    $this->load->library('calendar', $conf);
    echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);
}
```